# CakePHP issue when downloading csv file in safari on OS X

Tags: cakephp, csv, cakephp-2.0, export-to-csv

Following is the controller function that returns the csv file:

```
public function export(){

    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    $employee = $this->request->query['employee'];
    $from = $this->request->query['from'];
    $to = $this->request->query['to'];

    $events = $this->Event->export($employee, $from, $to);

    $this->response->download("export.csv");
    $this->set(compact('events'));
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    return;

}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    $this->Html->image('export.png', array('width'=>'200px', 'height'=>'79px')),
    array(
        'controller' => 'events',
        'action' => 'export',
        '?' => array(
            'employee'=>$_POST['data']['Event']['employee'],
            'from'=>$_POST['data']['Event']['from'],
            'to'=>$_POST['data']['Event']['to'],
            'ext'=>'csv'
        )
    ),
    array('escape'=>false)
);
```

It is working all good on every platform and browser except from safari on OS X. After I try to download it on safari (only on OS X), the file is getting a `.html` extension.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem? no downloading? browser get stuck? not the right cvs file? downloading link doesn't show?

Comment: Why not using https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-csvview - this uses a clean view-less approach that definitly works.

Comment: @Nunser, sorry for not mentioning it, but the question is now updated. So what is wrong is that, the browser adds .html extension.

Comment: @mark, I do not really want to user any external plugins is this is going to take more time to set up, and wil lbe harder to adapt when upgrading cakePHP one day. Or is it not the case?

Comment: No that is not the case. Its a one-liner to add, and a one-liner to use. And you wouldn't even have to ask this question in the first place. So what does now take more time to set up? :)

Comment: @mark, you have got me.. But now there is one more question for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570123/cakephp-placing-array-items-into-diferrent-cells-csvview-plugin